# Typecasting one function into another in golang

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
package vault

type Client interface {
    GetHealth() error
}

func (c DefaultClient)  GetHealth () error {
    resp := &VaultHealthResponse{}
    err := c.get(resp, "/v1/sys/health")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now, I want to use this function as part of this struct:

```
type DependencyHealthFunction func() error

type Dependency struct {
    Name           string `json:"name"`
    Required       bool   `json:"required"`
    Healthy        bool   `json:"healthy"`
    Error          error  `json:"error,omitempty"`
    HealthFunction DependencyHealthFunction
}
```

Basically, set the value of HealthFunction to GetHealth. Now, when I do the following:

```
func (config *Config) GetDependencies() *health.Dependency {
    vaultDependency := health.Dependency{
        Name: "Vault",
        Required: true,
        Healthy: true,
        HealthFunction: vault.Client.GetHealth,
    }
    temp1 := &vaultDependency
    return temp1;
}
```

This gives me an error and it says `cannot use vault.Client.GetHealth (type func(vault.Client) error) as type health.DependencyHealthFunction in field value`. How can I do this?

Edit: How DependencyHealthFunction is used?

As its part of Dependency struct, it's simply used as following: `d.HealthFunction()` where d is a variable of type `*Dependency`.

Comment: The function DependencyHealthFunction does not have any arguments.  The function vault.Client.GetHealth has one argument (the receiver).  Explain more about how you intended to use the function. Is their code that will supply that argument?

Comment: @CeriseLimon, I hope my edit explains this.

Comment: OK, you are not supplying the argument to the function on call.  Where to you intend to supply the argument to vault.Client.GetHealth (the argument is type `DefaultClient`).  Where does the `DefaultClient` value come from?

Comment: What function do you want to set as the value of `HealthFunction`? `vault.Client.GetHealth` does not refer to a specific function, according to the code you posted (`vault.Client` is the interface, not an object of type `vault.Client`).

Answer (score 0):

This is abstract:

```
    HealthFunction: vault.Client.GetHealth,
```

If we were to call `HealthFunction()`, what code do you expect to run? `vault.Client.GetHealth` is just a promise that such a function exists; it isn't a function itself. `Client` is just an interface.

You need to create something that conforms to `Client` and pass *its* `GetHealth`. For example, if you had a existing `DefaultClient` such as:

```
defaultClient := DefaultClient{}
```

Then you could pass its function:

```
    HealthFunction: defaultClient.GetHealth,
```

Now when you later call `HealthFunction()` it will be the same as calling `defaultClient.GetHealth()`.

https://play.golang.org/p/9Lw7uc0GaE

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to understanding how interfaces are treated in Go.

An interface simply defines a method or set of methods that a particular type must satisfy to be considered as "implementing" the interface.

For example:

```
import "fmt"

type Greeter interface {
    SayHello() string
}

type EnglishGreeter struct{}

// Satisfaction of SayHello method
func (eg *EnglishGreeter) SayHello() string {
    return "Hello"
}

type SpanishGreeter struct{}

func (sg *SpanishGreeter) SayHello() string {
    return "Ola"
}

func GreetPerson(g Greeter) {
    fmt.Println(g.SayHello())
}

func main() {
    eg := &EnglishGreeter{}

    sg := &SpanishGreeter{}

    // greet person in english
    GreetPerson(eg)

    // greet person in spanish
    GreetPerson(sg)
}
```

You can add this behavior into a custom struct by simply having a Greeter field inside the struct. ie

```
type FrontEntrance struct {
    EntranceGreeter Greeter
}

fe := &FrontEntrance { EntranceGreeter: &EnglishGreeter{} }

// then call the SayHello() method like this
fe.EntranceGreeter.SayHello()
```

Interfaces in golang are useful for composing common expected behavior for  types based on the methods that they satisfy.

Hope this helps.